# Linear problem with min of hyperbolic functions as the objective

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, linearization

I am trying to convert the problem below to linear programming problem and solve it with simplex algorithm. I am aware that converting max and min in goal function usually means adding proper constraints, however hyperbolic constraints are illegal in LPP. What am I missing here?

$$
\text{minimize} \left( \min\{\frac{1}{2x_1 + x_2}, \frac{1}{x_1 + x_2 + 1} \}\right) \\
x_1 + 2x_2 \leq 10 \\
x_1 + x_2 \leq 7 \\
x_1 \geq 2, x_2 \geq 0
$$

Comment: I would minimice the first function and then the other function. Then take the smaller result.

Comment: @RobPratt It´s up to you to post an answer. I don´t write comments or answers if an OP shows no interest.

Comment: @callculus min of the first is 1/14 at (7, 0) and min of the second is 1/8 at (a, 7-a). This would mean we can simply take the first one, right?

Comment: Hmm, btw I am pretty sure the first one is smaller than the second in the whole constrained region. That would probably help as well?

Comment: It seems that you have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x_1\ge 2 >1$ implies that $2x_1+x_2>x _1+x_2+1$, so $1/(2x_1+x_2)<1/(x_1+x_2+1)$, so you can replace the inner $\min$ with the first minimand.  Because the denominator is positive, minimizing $1/(2x_1+x_2)$ is equivalent to maximizing $2x_1+x_2 $.  Your solution $x=(7,0)$ is optimal for the resulting maximization LP, with objective value $14$, so the optimal objective value for the original problem is $1/14$.